# Is document directory path constant for iOS device?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am saving video/image in document directory.Now once the image is saved in document directory I want to save its reference in my local database.So I am thinking I can save URL of the image in the local database.

So is it constant throughout my app?

Answer (score 1):

It's not constant, i have observed every time you launch the app it'll be different, but your data is moved to this new path. You can save your file name in your database, and dynamically append this file name to NSDocument directory.

```
- (NSString *)documentsFilePath:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths firstObject];
    NSString *filePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    return filePath;
}


- (void)storeFile:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSString *filePath = [self documentsFilePath:fileName];

    // create if needed
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {

        // Write your data to file system here...
    }
}

- (void)deleteFile:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSString *filePath = [self documentsFilePath:fileName];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSError *deleteErr = nil;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&deleteErr];
        if (deleteErr) {
            NSLog(@"Can't delete %@: %@", filePath, deleteErr);
        }
    }
}
```

Please handle `nil` checks and store only filename in DB

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not constant. Whenever your app reinstall or updated on device the document directory will change, because when app installed on device os made an directory for app with some random id and each install this random it get changed by OS.

So, you need to make it dynamic own your own, like store the file name only and append the document directory path while using it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest only saving the filename or subdirectory/filename (if you have a subdirectory) in the database and then only attaching that to the NSDocumentDirectory.

This will ensure that you always know where the file is...

NSDocumentDirectory is however consistent accross updates, so the files should remain in the document directory even if you update...

Comment: To be precise, the path relative to document directory is consistent. The absolute path is not consistent.